# Refactor whole data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that I have read from disk and then applied a filter:

```
df <- df[ df$x > 10, ]
```

**Question:** How can I refactor all factors in the data frame now that several rows have been removed?

Comment: Check out `?droplevels`. Also, your lapply could be slightly simplified to: `df[] <- lapply(df, function (x) if (is.factor(x)) factor(x) else x)`

Comment: @beginneR thanks - if you post your response as an answer, I can +1 it!

Comment: Not necessary since it's a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function (x) if (is.factor(x)) factor(x) else x))
```

Source: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Refactor-all-factors-in-a-data-frame-tp826749p826754.html